# Tailwind - How to customize padding such as px-10

Tags: tailwind-css

In Tailwind, I want to customize **px-10** to equal

```
padding-left: 10; 
padding-right: 10px;
```

How do I do that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add custom padding values as shown in their [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#customizing)

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      spacing: {
       sm: '10px',
      }
    }
  }
```

and use it as

```
<div class="px-sm"> .. <div/>
```

**OR**

Use your custom values inside class by using [JIT mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support)

```
<div className="pl-[10px] pr-[10px]"> .. </div>
```